# Is there a way to stop all other events in a dojo onBlur event handler?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

Maybe I'm on the wrong track...

**The setup:**
I have a rather complex full dojofied web application. The important part for this question is a longish form in the central region of a `dijit.layout.BorderContainer` with a navigation tree and some action buttons in the other regions.

**What I want to do:**
If the user did enter data and did not save, they should get a warning message if he is going to leave the form (if he navigates away, klicks the "new Element" button,...). For a better user experience, I wanted to give a modal dialog with the options "save", "leave anyway", "cancel".
May idea was to use the onBlur event of the form, stop all other events (most likely an onClick on some other widget), check for changes, if there are changes, display the dialog, otherwise let the other events continue.
I do not want to add a checkChanges method to all non-form active elements!

For a first test I just tried to stop the events...

**This works**

```
<div id="formArea" dojoType="dijit.form.Form" encoding="multipart/form-data" action=""  class="ContentPane" region="center">
   <script type="dojo/connect" event="onBlur" >
      alert("I don't think so");
    </script>
 </div>
```

...but it's ugly and I can't easily continue

**This doesn't**

```
<div id="formArea" dojoType="dijit.form.Form" encoding="multipart/form-data" action=""  class="ContentPane" region="center">
   <script type="dojo/connect" event="onBlur" args="e">
      console.log("blur"); // ok
      e.preventDefault();//event.stopt(e)//return false //<--neither of these
    </script>
 </div>
```

the problem is that if I click on a button outside of the form, the `onBlur` triggers, but I can't stop the `onClick` on the button.
I know that `onBlur` doesn't deliver an event object - so the `e.something` can't really work...
Is there any way to catch the `onClick` on the other element?

Comment: the problem is that the browser may have N events running. the onBlur above only prevents actions on One of them, the current onBlur-event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is afaik only `confirm('question?')` that will 'deadlock' the events of your page like that.

I have made a similar setup though, the way I came around this (except if user enters url in addressbar and hits enter) was a popup dialog whenever the navigation tree is clicked, sending user to a new view. Consider:

```
----------------------------------------
| Nav 1  |   Asset1 ( view controller )  |
| Nav 2  |   Asset2 ( hidden )           |
----------------------------------------
```

Nav 1 is the default onload view, Asset 1 is loaded, contains a 'setup page' form or similar and can be changed. The trick is, Asset1 and Asset2 is derivative from AbstractAsset which in turn is a simple ContentPane extension.

In AbstractAsset is a 'must-override-for-functionality' function called `isDirty`

```
var Viewcontroller = declare("AbstractAsset", [dijit.ContentPane], {
       isDirty: function() { return false; }
});


declare("Asset1", [Viewcontroller], {

startup: function() {
  // sets up form
  ...
  // and references inputfields to 'this'
  this.inputfields = this.form.getChildren();

  // and saves (clones) the state of each field
  var self = this;
  this.inputfields.forEach(function(inputWidget) {
     self.states[inputWidget.id] = inputWidget.get("value");
  });
},
isDirty: function() {
  var self = this;
  var dirty = false;
  this.form.getChildren().some(input) {
     if(self.states[input.id] != input.get("value")) {
        dirty = true;
        return false; // breaks .some loop
     }
     return true;
  });
  return dirty;
}

})
```

Then in turn, every navigation click must call the currently visible view controller's isDirty function in order to procede. Lets say user clicks the nav-tree (dijit.Tree) row node *Nav 2*.

```
var navigation = dojo.declare("NavigationController", [dijit.Tree], {
 currentView : null,
 onLoad: function() {
   // start Asset1 in viewNode by default
   this.currentView = new Asset1({ }, this.viewNode); 
 },
 onClick : function() {
    if(this.currentView.isDirty()) alert("I Dont Think So");
    else {
       this.loadFunction(this.model.selection.getSelected());
    }
 }

});
```

This is the general idea of implementing the on-unload-check, you Will need to hook any onClick events through your 'master application controller' to determine what should happen. [Check this application](https://github.com/mschr/oocms/blob/master/admin/include/application.js) which serves as cms navigation controller and its [page.js:587](https://github.com/mschr/oocms/blob/master/admin/include/page.js) for isDirty example

Comment: thanks for the ideas! I need to think about them a bit. As with phusicks answer I'm a bit sad that I still have to touch the other (non-form) elements, but it seems like it's the only way

Comment: im afraid so m8 :) the event fired in one DOM is hidden to event fired from another

Comment: hard choice between the two answers, I think this is nearer to what I can use in our architecture.

Answer (score 2):

[Pause button event listener(s)](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on#pausable-function) in form's `onBlur` if data are not saved.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/A5DHf/

You have some button event listeners, register them via `on.pausable(node, event, callback)` instead of `on()`:

```
var b1Handler = on.pausable(button1Node, "click", function() {
    console.log("b1.onClick");        
});

var b2Handler = on.pausable(button2Node, "click", function() {
    console.log("b2.onClick");        
});
```

Gather handlers into an array:

```
var handlersToPause = [b1Handler, b2Handler];
```

Add `onBlur` event listener:

```
on(form, "blur", function(e) {

    if (this.isDirty()) {
        // if data are not saved, pause button event listeners
        handlersToPause.forEach(function(handler) {
            handler.pause();
        });
        // display modal dialog here     
    }            
});
```

Add e.g. `onFocus` event listener to resume button event listeners:

```
on(form, "focus", function(e) {
    handlersToPause.forEach(function(handler) {
        handler.resume();            
    });
});
```

Please note, that `handler.pause()` is pausing an `onclick` listener, not an event. The `onclick` event is waiting in the `Event queue` and therefore is not accessible in the execution time of `onblur`.

I would work out some more robust solution, but this is quick and answers your question. Anyway, have a look at `dojo/aspect` and its [`around` advice](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/aspect#around) to call your *checkChanges* without the need to change *all non-form active elements.*

Comment: thanks for the ideas. `on()` and `dojo/aspect` are new to me, I definitly need to take a look at them. At the moment we are stuck with dojo 1.6, though :/

Comment: You can do more or less the same w/ Dojo 1.6, just use `dojo.connect` instead of both `dojo/on` and `dojo/aspect`.

Comment: yea neet thing with the pause thing ^^ however, the working-with-no-controller-all-being-anonymous architecture will hurt in the end.. the question is, if all browsers invoke onblur and onclick synchroniously - just tested your fiddle in FF and here it works as should. The changes made in your fiddle, saves values every time form focuses and isDirty checks those against current values http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/A5DHf/16/